# Как подключится к Redis Cloud?

Tags: python, redis, redis-server

Пытаюсь подключится к бд Rediscloud как написано в документации, Но код выдает ошибку, подскжаите в чем причина и как решить

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis(
host='redis-12062.c3.eu-west-1-1.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com',
port="12062")

r.set('foo', 'bar')

r.get('foo')
```

Выдает ошибку
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "g:\Redis_learn\main.py", line 7, in 
r.set('foo', 'bar')
File "G:\Redis_learn\venvredis\lib\site-packages\redis\commands\core.py", line 2342, in set
return self.execute_command("SET", *pieces, **options)
File "G:\Redis_learn\venvredis\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 540, in execute_command
conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
File "G:\Redis_learn\venvredis\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 1104, in get_connection
connection.connect()
File "G:\Redis_learn\venvredis\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 282, in connect
raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 11002 connecting to redis-12062.c3.eu-west-1-1.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com:12062. getaddrinfo failed.